# Fetch request getting cancelled, when executing click event

Tags: javascript, fetch, window.location

I have a "click event" on an element, which first locate window by window.location.href, then fetch data from server and then renders HTML, however i am not getting desired output as fetch request is getting cancelled, why?

```
async function retrieveItems(category='any', sub_cat='any') {
    let url;
    if(category === "any") {
        url = "_items/";
    }
    else {
        url = "_items/"+category+"/"+sub_cat+"/";
    }
    let response = await fetch(url);
    if(response.ok) {
        let responseData = await response.json();
        return responseData;
    }
}

// Retreiving and Rendering Items on items.html
async function items_sub_cat(event) {
    window.location.href = 'items.html';
    let category = event.currentTarget.parentNode.parentNode.previousSibling.innerHTML;
    let sub_category_name = event.currentTarget.innerHTML;
    let responseData = await retrieveItems(category, sub_category_name);
    renderItems(responseData, "items_by_sub_cat");
    buttons();    
}



let sub_category = document.getElementsByClassName("sub_category_name");
for(let i=0; i<sub_category.length; i++) {
    sub_category[i].addEventListener("click", items_sub_cat);
}
```

Can anybody help in this regard?

Comment: do you intend to change the page to `/items.html` first and then get/render items?

Comment: Yes, exactly first change page to items.html, then retreive data and then render it

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you forget to suppress the event?
Try adding `event.preventDefault()` to the click listener function.